# Select the closest radio input

Tags: jquery

I have dom like the following

```
 <input type="radio" name="day_time[]" class="pickup-location-day" value="Sunday"> Sunday
 <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:00am"> 02:00am
 <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:30am"> 02:30am
 <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="05:30am"> 05:30am<br>

  <input type="radio" name="day_time[]" class="pickup-location-day" value="Sunday"> Monday
 <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:00am"> 02:00am
 <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:30am"> 02:30am
 <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="05:30am"> 05:30am<br>

 etc ....
```

i want to bind when select `.pickup-location-time` with the first `.pickup-location-day`, like when the user select the `.pickup-location-time` closest '.pickup-location-day' should selected also .

note that i used the following

```
$('.pickup-location-time').on('change', function() {
   $(this).closest('.pickup-location-time').prop('checked', true);
})
```

but this couldn't help

[image]

Comment: look in jQuery API at what `closest()` is used for. Would find it doesn't do what you want unless your radios are wrapped in groups elements

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your radios into groups so you can traverse within specific group. This simplifies isolating instances

```
<div class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="day_time[]" class="pickup-location-day" value="Sunday">Sunday
    <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:00am">02:00am
    <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:30am">02:30am
    <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="05:30am">05:30am       
</div>
<div class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="day_time[]" class="pickup-location-day" value="Sunday">Monday
    <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:00am">02:00am
    <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="02:30am">02:30am
    <input type="radio" name="pickup_time[]" class="pickup-location-time" value="05:30am">05:30am       
</div>
```

Then you can do:

```
$('.pickup-location-time').on('change', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.pickup-location-day').prop('checked', true);
})
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pnLnjfvy/)**</kbd>

Comment: That's good idea by wrapping them in a div. But OP wanted to select next to .pickup-location-time..

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal this does what I interpret OP to be asking. It correctly checks the `day` within proper group

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal your interpretation is different than the way I read it

Comment: May be you're right but OP is making me confusion. I read again and seems to be the way you're doing but in OP's code getting `time` not day. So confusion... anyway that's OP's choice. +1

Comment: @charlietfl i tried it but for some reason it select only the last `.pickup-location-day`, not the next one

Comment: really not clear what the behavior wanted is. Maybe `$(this).parent().next().find('.pickup-location-day').prop('checked', true);`

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for help but i only need the closest radio to be chosen when i select the time range like in the image , using find get all the descendants

Answer (score 0):

Use `prev()`

```
$(this).prev('.pickup-location-day').prop('checked', true);
```

Be sure to select `.pickup-location-day`.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, `.closest()` does something quite different.

If you control the document structure, why don't you just use `$(this).next('.pickup-location-time')`, as it's always the next element you want to select?